# How can we convert ajax GET request into fetch API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

```
function myFunction(username, mess_id) {
        mess = document.getElementById(mess_id);
        mess.innerText = "Sending...";
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/user/resend',
                data: {usr:username},
                success: function(data){
                        mess.innerText = data;
                }
        })
}
```

In fetch API I have written as:

```
message = document.getElementById('mess_id');
message.innerText = 'Sending...';
fetch(url)
.then(data => data.text())
.then(mess => message.innerText = mess)
```

But, what about the data attribute of the ajax function.

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)?

Comment: Or even a web search for something like "send data javascript fetch" or similar surely would have gotten you started

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: It looks like `fetch` isn't correctly implemented and doesn't allow a body in a GET request although the specification allows it.

Comment: Here are some discussions on this topic: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/551 I'm not following it so I don't know the current state and if `fetch` is going to support a body in a GET request in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send a GET request, which should hold data only in the query string, and not in the request payload.

Therefore, you can use this to send the user:

```
function myFunction(username, mess_id) {
        mess = document.getElementById(mess_id);
        mess.innerText = "Sending...";
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/user/resend?usr=' + username,
                success: function(data){
                        mess.innerText = data;
                }
        })
}
```

However, if you still want to send `data: {usr:username}` in the request body, you can send a POST request like this using `fetch`:

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.text();  JavaScript objects
}

postData('/user/resend', {usr:username})
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Nothing preventing using fetch as GET. There are numerous ways to create the query string. Suggesting OP needs to change methods may not be viable

Comment: I said 'should' and not 'cannot'. According to the official documentation of the GET request on MDN, "The HTTP GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only be used to request data (they shouldn't include data)." "Sending body/payload in a GET request may cause some existing implementations to reject the request — while not prohibited by the specification, the semantics are undefined. It is better to just avoid sending payloads in GET requests." See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET